# Google Authenticator for Gaia Online

Tags: lg, lg-g4

So, I hooked up an Authenticator to my account on ***Gaia Online***. My phone did a factory reset, so I lost my codes, and now I've lost everything.
I can't get back into my account and so much effort went into it.

What can I do? Can I get the codes back?

I wrote a ticket to the staff, but they haven't gotten back to me and it has been a while.

Comment: That's about all you can do.  Happened to me with my Origin account and their chat support wouldn't load for me so I couldn't get any help.  I said to hell with it all and deleted all that Origin crap.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recovery token they are supposed to give you, if they didn't, yell at them for not giving last hope tokens.

You can also contact support, as you already did.

Comment: It would be a nice addition to mention other, synchronized Authenticator apps like Authy. Those can help you to not lose access to all your 2-factor accounts.

Comment: They could leak the token if something else than itself can touch, see the token.